# Azure Data Facory - Connect to google's Firebase DB

Tags: azure-data-factory

My client would like to extract some data from a Firebase/Firestore database with Azure Data Factory. I'm not seeing an obvious way to make this connection.

Any slick ways to connect to Firebase from Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Hi Phil Lachmann, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answer?.This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Data factory doesn't support the google's Firebase DB connector.

We could not find the Google Firebase DB connector in all the supported database connector list:

[image]

For more details, please reference: [Azure Data Factory connector overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview)

Others also post a [Google Firebase Connector support](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/39632509-google-firebase-connector) request in Data Factory feedback, but still no responds:

[image]

Hope this helps.